# Selenium Webdriver Python using XPATH found text from column 1 of html table how do i go to column 3

Tags: css, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with some columns.  Using XPATH I have found the text from the Name column.  This is column index [1]
From here I want to continue my XPATH and go to the the 3rd column.  Index [3]
I do not know how to continue my XPATH to get to the 3rd column.

My XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="analysis_reports_ct_fields_body"]//span[contains(text(), "Matches")]
```

If you look at the HTML below the text View is in the 3rd column.  I do not want to use the text View because that text is blank sometimes.

The HTML is:

```
<table id="analysis_reports_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBHG">
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-695" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="linkhover" title="Matches" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Matches</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-696" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="" title="manual" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">manual</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-697" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="linkhover block" title="view" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">view</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-698" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-699" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="" title="Source records" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Source records</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-700" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="" title="29/10/2015 14:47:21" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">29/10/2015 14:47:21</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-701" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="block" title="" style="">498</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBBH">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-702" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <span class="" title="INFOSHARE\riaz.ladhani" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Company\riaz.ladhani</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GLKP2TGBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
        </tbody>
</table>
```

If i do the following XPATH a lot of the sections of the table is highlighted

```
//table[@id="analysis_reports_ct_fields_body"]//span[contains(text(), "Matches")]//ancestor::div
```

Can i somehow use ancestor perhaps to get to the 3rd column?

If i try //descendant::* this not highlight anything.  I thought descendant should go down the tree, ancestor goes up the tree

```
//table[@id="analysis_reports_ct_fields_body"]//span[contains(text(), "Matches")]//descendant::*
```

My method will accept a parameter called Name (this is column 1 of the table, the text "Matches" is in there) and then from here I would like to find the 3rd column of the table.

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: HTML looks wrong, TD inside of another TD are you sure about it?

Comment: your html fragment is sheer invalid thus i failed to test it. `//span[contains(text(), "Matches")]/ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[2]//text()` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Xpath.

```
//table[@id='analysis_reports_ct_fields_body']//td[.//span[contains(text(), 'Matches')]]/following-sibling::td[2]
```

The above Xpath looks for the `td` tag in the table which contains the `span` containing text `Matches` and navigates to its second sibling(column at index 3).
This Xpath eliminates the need for traversing back in the DOM.

Comment: Do you use an online XPath tester? If so, which one? Just trying to build my toolkit... :)

Comment: I use the default web developer console in Firefox or chrome. Press F12 and find the console tab. Inside the console type your xpath within `$x("xpath")` and press enter to test it.